# Como implementar Navigation Drawer com Bottom Navigation na mesma aplicação

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

Em um *app* que tenha `NavigationDrawer` com *Bottom Navigation*, qual seria o caminho recomendado para implementação? Procurei por tutoriais e não achei nem na documentação oficial.
Criei uma aplicação baseada no modelo `NavigationDrawer` do Android Studio e depois adicionei a *BottomBar*. Estou na dúvida se a `BottomNavigationView` deve ser adicionada no `content_main.xml`, na `activity_main.xml` ou no `app_bar_main.xml`. Existe alguma diferença de desempenho entre as três opções?